# very thin seedlings

Tags: seedlings

I have been trying to grow Celosia (Cockscomb) from last 3-4 months. Most seeds get germinated in 3-4 days after potting. They grow upto almost 2 inches tall with two leaves on top but after this stage they start damping off.

See picture here [Celosia seedlings are damping off](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33613/celosia-seedlings-are-damping-off)

As suggested in an answer above I tried by putting them in indirect sunlight i.e. near a window where sunlight is not direct. I also need to care if surface is getting dried up or not.

But nothing is working out they start damping off after 2 inches tall.

Please suggest what can be done?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert and have not grown Celosia specifically but the seedlings in your image look very tall and thin which is usually a symptom of not enough sunlight in the first few days of life.  I would start with fresh seeds in new potting soil and before they germinate place them on a sunny windowsill or outside on your sunny porch.  That way they get plenty of sun right away.

Damping off can occur because of pathogens in the soil so I would start with fresh potting soil in a plastic container with good drainage.  Your cardboard container might be holding too much moisture.  Only water the seedlings when you poke your finger down below the soil surface and it feels dry.  In conclusion, my best guess is too much water/dampness and especially not enough sun as soon as they germinate.

Comment: If OP initially has them under fluorescent or LED lights (which don't give off a lot of heat), then they should get those lights as close to the plants as possible without them touching the lights, otherwise they will "stretch" to get closer to the insufficiently intense (aka "not the sun") light source.